# Eclipse CDT compiles additional things when doing "build project" or "build all"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a simple eclipse CDT project with a very simple makefile. When I hit build-all, it complies the makefile, but also compiles some additional things which take 3-5 seconds more (and it is annoying).

[image: additional compilation image 1]
[image: additional compilation image 2]

Any ideas why this happens to me? This happens on Eclipse Indigo, on OSX Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is compiled for "scanner discovery" (google this for more). This helps Eclipse figure out what your default include files / settings are, so they can be used with internal scanner.

Comment: I think you need to look into project properties -> c/c++ build -> Discovery options -> automate discovery...